# dropdown item android not working

Tags: android

I have this piece of code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,Cities);
AutoCompleteTextView textedit =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
textedit.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*editText1 = an edittext in the app

Cities = array of string for the dropdown*

But the second line gives me an error, how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you check my answer ?

Comment: Didn't worked , I want when the user types for example E , The edit text shows "ECD" or "EDF"

Answer (score 0):

Change EditText to AutoCompleteTextView in XML layout file of the above activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use editText instead of "AutoCompleteTextView" in the xml.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/myAutoCompleteTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
      android:ems="10" />
```

Change with

```
AutoCompleteTextView textedit =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myAutoCompleteTextView);
```